# mysql select if datediff is greater than

Tags: mysql

I would like to query users from lat 3 years only if the time diffrence of date_start and date_end is greater than 3 months. I have tried a lot of things but nothing works. This is the statment i made until now :

```
SELECT accounts.account_id, accounts.name, accounts.active_club_id, 
accounts.phone, MIN(shifts_accounts.date_start) as 'datestart', MAX(shifts_accounts.date_end) as 'dateend' 
FROM `shifts_accounts` 
JOIN accounts ON shifts_accounts.account_id = accounts.account_id 
JOIN accounts_groups ON accounts.account_id = accounts_groups.account_id 
WHERE accounts_groups.group_id = 7 
AND DATEDIFF('dateend',  'datestart') > 90 
AND accounts.active_club_id != 1 
AND shifts_accounts.date_start > '2014-11-28' 
AND shifts_accounts.date_start < '2017-11-28' GROUP BY accounts.account_id
```

Comment: You cannot reference an alias in this way. But you can use HAVING in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example of a valid query. I don't think there's enough information to say whether it's what you want or not...

```
SELECT a.account_id
     , a.name
     , a.active_club_id
     , a.phone
     , MIN(sa.date_start) datestart
     , MAX(sa.date_end) dateend 
  FROM shifts_accounts sa
  JOIN accounts a
    ON a.account_id = sa.account_id 
  JOIN accounts_groups ag
    ON ag.account_id = a.account_id 
 WHERE ag.group_id = 7 
   AND a.active_club_id != 1 
   AND sa.date_start BETWEEN '2014-11-28' AND '2017-11-28' 
 GROUP 
    BY a.account_id
HAVING DATEDIFF(dateend, datestart) > 90;
```

For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I love you :) tahnk you very much and thank you for the related link.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
SELECT accounts.account_id, accounts.name, accounts.active_club_id, 
accounts.phone, MIN(shifts_accounts.date_start) as 'datestart', MAX(shifts_accounts.date_end) as 'dateend' 
FROM `shifts_accounts` 
JOIN accounts ON shifts_accounts.account_id = accounts.account_id 
JOIN accounts_groups ON accounts.account_id = accounts_groups.account_id 
WHERE accounts_groups.group_id = 7 
AND DATEDIFF('dateend',  'datestart') > 90 
AND accounts.active_club_id != 1 
AND shifts_accounts.date_start < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 YEAR) GROUP BY accounts.account_id
```

Comment: Thats a little helpful. thank you. it wasn't exacly what i mean so i will just edit my question to make it sure to understand for you.

Comment: With or without inverted commas, `WHERE ... dateend` is never going to be a valid solution here.